# Best course of action towards someone who referred me to company, who has mistreated me?

Tags: professionalism, referral

I've been referred to a company by an acquaintance. I've passed all the interview stages, but in the meantime, the person referring me has treated me very badly, and done some things I'd rather not discuss here.

What concerns me, is that the person will get a significant referral bonus if I accept the job offer, and I don't feel alright with that after what happened. I'd like to take the job opportunity, but this means that this person would benefit from it.

Naturally, this has me a bit upset and I'd rather not have this person benefit after his treatment of me.

What would be the best way to proceed to limit any benefit to him while maintaining professionalism?

Comment: Is that person working there ? If you're employed, would you work with or near him ? Depending of the answer, I'am not sure if the current accepted answer is good. If you would work with him, that would be quite a red flag to look somewhere else to me.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Regardless of whether you and this person get along well or not, they *did* refer you to the company. Your only purpose in trying to take away the referral bonus is to be vindictive to someone who has treated you poorly. By even asking about preventing the referral, you will make yourself look petty and spiteful to the interviewers.

Take your job, forget about the person who referred you, and move on.

Comment: Yes, being professional means taking your personal issues out of the equation sometimes.

Answer (score 5):

> is there any way for me to get the job and skip the bonus for the
>   referring person?

Not at any company that I know of, have heard of, or can imagine. Your ex-friend fulfilled their part of the deal with the company, and the company will fulfil their part of the deal with your ex-friend.

Failing to do so could possibly result in a lawsuit from the ex-friend against the company (possibly followed by another for wrongful dismissal).